# Is there a way to preserve data when reading Excel sheet?

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using [read-excel-file.min.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/read-excel-file@4.0.6/README.md) to read and display excel data on a HTML table. The issue I am encountering is that the certain data is being changed when loaded to the table.

Example, if a row contains the value 7% in the excel sheet, when loaded to the HTML table, it will display 0.07. The same occurs for the dates. If the date format is 11/08/2022, it will change the following to Tue Nov 08 2022 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time).

[image]

Here is the following jsfiddle (below is the code as well): https://jsfiddle.net/RobGamer/o9Lbzjw1/50/

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
    var input = document.querySelector('#grab-excel-file');
 
  input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){
      var i = 0;
      data.map((row,index)=>{
        console.log(data);
        if(i == 0){
          let table = document.querySelector('#tbl-excel-data');
          generateTableHead(table, row);
        }

        if(i > 0){
          let table = document.querySelector('#tbl-excel-data');
          generateTableRows(table, row);
        }
        i++;
      });
    });
  });
  
  function generateTableHead(table, data){
    let thead = table.createTHead();
    
    for(let key of data){
        let th = document.createElement('th');
      let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      th.appendChild(text);
      thead.appendChild(th);
    }
  }
  
  function generateTableRows(table, data){
    let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    data.map((row,index)=>{
        let newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      let newText = document.createTextNode(row);
      console.log(newText);
      newCell.appendChild(newText);
    });
  }
  
  function formatDate(dte){
    var date = new Date(dte);
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [mnth, day, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
  }
```

```css
th { background-color: black; color:white !important; font-family: sans-serif !important; text-align:center !important; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #CCC; text-align::left; }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p><input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" id="grab-excel-file"></p>
      <!-- Dummy Excel File -->
      <table id="tbl-excel-data" class="table"></table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to grab the 'cell type' using the CELL formula in     excel.

[this is where I came up with the idea](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)

Comment: How would I grab the 'cell type'?

Comment: https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/excel-data-formatter-in-java-with-code-examples/

How do I use Xssfcellstyle?

Method Summary Make a copy of this style. Color is optional. Get the index of the number format (numFmt) record used by this cell format. Get the background fill color.